# POST http://localhost:8000/offers-ajax/store 419 (unknown status) Laravel AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, forms, request

I'm a beginner in AJAX and trying to post data form by using AJAX, but this error shows in the console:

> POST http://localhost:8000/offers-ajax/store 419 (unknown status)

I do not know why; I tried a lot but nothing seems to work.

I tried to post data without using AJAX queries and it works fine.

These are the routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'offers-ajax'],function(){

    Route::get('/create','AjaxController@create')-> name('ajax.offer.create');
    Route::post('/store','AjaxController@store')-> name('ajax.offer.store');

});
```

Controller:

```
public function store(OffersRequest $request)
{
    $file_name = $this->saveImage($request->photo, 'images/offers');

    // Offer::create($request -> except(['_token']));
    Offer::create([
        'photo' => $file_name,
        'name_ar' => $request->name_ar,
        'name_en' => $request->name_en,
        'details_ar' => $request->details_ar,
        'details_en' => $request->details_en,
        'price' => $request->price,

    ]);

}
```

blade create page:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">

<form method="POST" class="needs-validation" novalidate action=""
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">chose Photo</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="photo">
        @error('photo')
        <small class="form-text text-danger">{{$message}}</small>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Name">{{__('messages.create_name')}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name_ar"  placeholder="Enter name">
        @error('name_ar')
        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
        @enderror

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Name">{{__('messages.create_name_en')}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name_en"  placeholder="Enter name">
        @error('name_en')
        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
        @enderror

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price">{{__('messages.create_price')}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" placeholder="price here">
        @error('price')
        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="details">{{__('messages.create_details')}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="details" name="details_ar" placeholder="details here">
        @error('details_ar')
        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="details">{{__('messages.create_details_en')}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="details" name="details_en" placeholder="details here">
        @error('details_en')
        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <button type="button" id="save_offer" class="btn btn-primary">create</button>


</form>
</div>
@stop

@section('script')
<script>

    $(document).on('click', '#save_offer', function(){

    $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
        url: "{{Route('ajax.offer.store')}}",
        data:  {},
        success: function (data){

        }, error: function (reject){

        }
    });

    });

</script>
@stop
```

Please could you help me

Comment: you need to add ajax set up to send the token in the header, this is the proper way, other way is to send the token through ajax call, ur problem is with VerifyCsrfToken

Comment: Is that line 419 or http status code 419?

Comment: it's 419 code @ProfessorAbronsius

Comment: how could u explain

Comment: Ok - I thought that code was `"I'm a teapot"` but that is 418... my bad.

Comment: ajax data field is empty, is that on purpose? and no csrf token attached with ajax call

Comment: @MahmoudDiab, added answer to explain, check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add meta tag in your html page

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then in js
add this in the beginning

```
$.ajaxSetup({
data: {
    _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
 }
});
```